# How can I get not nil for value of status in [String:Any] dictionary that I got from my firebase database?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nsdictionary

```
 self.ref.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "phoneNumber").queryEqual(toValue: self.userMobile).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

 if snapshot.value is NSNull{

    print("Not exists in database")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue1", sender: self)
 }

 else{
     // Get user value
     let value = snapshot.value as! [String : Any]

     print(value)
     let status = value["status"] as? Int

     print ("User status is : \(status)")
     if status == 0 {

         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue1", sender: self)
     }                 
     else if status == 1 {                       
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue2", sender: self)
     }
```

[image]

Comment: I get this result  from running :

Comment: userID : Optional("rtknqiuIRTXj6fVE3uhy72")
{
    "-LFzlX9GJWtr" =     {
        birthDate = "1995/07/12";
        location = " ";
        phoneNumber = "+189217055241";
        profilePhoto = "";
        reportStatus = 0;
        score = 0;
        sex = M;
        status = 1;
        username = John;
    };
}
User status is  : nil

Comment: Copy/paste the response in your question (by edit), not in comment. Also, could your format your code and add text to your question, not only code.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are not getting just one user but a list of users (and if you have just one user, a list with one user).

So do a loop like this :

```
for user in value.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
{
    let status = user.childSnapshot(forPath: "status").value as? Int
    print ("User status is : \(status)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I wasn't getting all users and it got ok when I changed.Value to .childAdded :         .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, to .observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded,